# How does ASP.NET decide that this request is for a WebForms page or an MVC app or a Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I understand that MVC and Web API (and off late it has even been included in the ASP.NET runtime to) have a routing engine that takes the URI and routes it to the right controller (or HttpHandler in the case of Web Forms).

But my question is -- the routing engine of MVC lives in a separate library, the MVC library. So even before the MVC routing engine comes to work, there must be something within the ASP.NET runtime that decides that the request is for MVC, so let's load the MVC library and then give the request to MVC's routing engine.

What component is that?

Answer (score 0):

Your web application is defined in `Global.asax.cs`. It inherits from different classes depending on what type of application it is. For instance, MVC apps inherit from the `MvcApplication` class.